# logger.debug not showing to console

Tags: slf4j

Below is my logback.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration scan="true">

    <include
        resource="org/springframework/boot/logging/logback/defaults.xml" />

    <appender name="STDOUT"
        class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <!-- <pattern>${CONSOLE_LOG_PATTERN}</pattern> -->
            <!-- <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%t] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n </pattern> -->
            <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss} %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n
            </pattern>
            <charset>utf8</charset>
        </encoder>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>DEBUG</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <appender name="db"
        class="ch.qos.logback.classic.db.DBAppender">
        <connectionSource
            class="ch.qos.logback.core.db.DriverManagerConnectionSource">
            <driverClass>org.postgresql.Driver</driverClass>
            <url>jdbc:postgresql://SERVER_IP:5432/MY_DB</url>
            <user>MY_USER</user>
            <password>MY_PASSWORD</password>
        </connectionSource>
        <filter class="ch.qos.logback.classic.filter.ThresholdFilter">
            <level>ERROR</level>
        </filter>
    </appender>
    <root level="info">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
        <appender-ref ref="db" />
    </root>
</configuration>
```

and I am logging using the code below

```
logger.debug("Debug message!");
```

But the log message does not appear on the console. However `logger.info` messages do show. How can I get debug messages to also appear on the console? I want both INFO and DEBUG to show in the console.

Answer (score 1):

Just change this line

```
<root level="info">
```

to

```
<root level="debug">
```

and you should be able to see the debug messages.

Comment: If this solved your problem, would you mind accepting the answer? Thanks.